# CQ5 IIS dispatcher module cache returning 000003E9 and empty page

Tags: windows, iis-7

I am trying to setup IIS 7.0 dispatcher module for CQ5 following the setup:
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/dispatcher/disp_install.html.

I am trying on windows 2008 sp2 64bit and a local publishing istance on port 4203.

The dispatcher works as long as cache is disabled, once I enable it, files are written in the document root but the homepage is returned empty and I get in my dispatcher.log:

```
[Fri Mar 07 16:38:24 2014] [D] [3180(2108)] checking [/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.html]
[Fri Mar 07 16:38:24 2014] [D] [3180(2108)] never flushed [E:\wwwroot2\.stat] -> use cache [E:\wwwroot2\content\geometrixx-outdoors\en.html]
[Fri Mar 07 16:38:24 2014] [D] [3180(2108)] cache-action for [/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.html]: SPOOL
[Fri Mar 07 16:38:24 2014] [D] [3180(2108)] request declined
[Fri Mar 07 16:38:24 2014] [I] [3180(2108)] "GET /content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.html" 0 - 0ms
[Fri Mar 07 16:38:24 2014] [W] [3180(2108)] HSE_REQ_EXEC_URL(/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.html) returned: 000003E9
```

I get a code 200 from my IIS 7.0

I gave modify permission to IUSER and tried also a

```
icacls e:\wwwroot2 /grant "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)(RX)
```

(should not be necessary since I am on 7.0 and not 7.5)
The dispatcher is installed as handler mapping

if I bypass cache with a query string as in

```
http://myserver/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.html?a=1
```

it works

any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer on adobe forum:

http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__arow-i_have_spentthepas.html#forum__arow-i_have_spentthepas__gmqe-from_error_seemslik

I was missing these steps:

> ```
> Click back on the site. And Double-Click Configuration Editor. 
> For Section dropdown list select system.webServer/handlers. For From select the Site. 
> Click the Count= field and select the … button
> Select CQ and change requireAccess to None. Close and click the Apply button (top/right corner).
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar issue, and I fixed it by setting the "required path" as `*` instead of `*.*` in window "Edit Script Map" in Handler Mappings.